# How to reference array JSON/HTML data types on JQUERY SUCCESS handler

Tags: jquery

I am trying to update multiple items, in the case span tags, through JQuery. I did manage to update a single item, using html dataType, but I have been unable to find the correct way to reference an array of items.

The problem seems to be in the setData function below. I was attempting to reference it as an ordinary array, but that does not seem to work.

This is the JQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".hook1").change(function () {
        pass_id = (this.value);
        var seltop = $(this).attr('id');
        var lastchar = seltop.slice(-1);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "comp_data.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                passval: pass_id,
                pass2: lastchar
            },
            success: function setData(data) {
                $("#price" + lastchar).html(data[0].price);
                $("#matricule" + lastchar).html(data[1].matricule);
                $("#tag" + lastchar).html(data[2].tag);
                $("#ins_yr1" + lastchar).html(data[3].ins_yr1);
                $("#Totalacq" + lastchar).html(data[4].Totalacq);
            }

        });
    });
});
</script>
```

This is the relevant portion of the comp_data.php file:

```
<?php
$version_id = $_REQUEST['passval'];
$i = $_REQUEST['pass2'];

mysql_query("CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vcomp AS (SELECT......");

$return = array(
    "price" = > "",
    "matricule" = > "",
    "tag" = > "",
    "ins_yr1" = > "",
    "Totalacq" = > ""
);

$name = array_keys($return);
$ct = count($name);
$n = 0;
while ($n < $ct) {
    $key = $name[$n];
    $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT *
    FROM vcomp
    ORDER BY segment_id,price
    ");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql2)) {
        $return[$key] = $row[$key];
    }
    $n++;
}
$returnJSON = json_encode($return);
echo $returnJSON;
```

This last echo of $returnJSON gives

```
{"price":"1014000","matricule":"10000","tag":"6000","ins_yr1":"25350","Totalacq":"1055350"}
```

And that's what I want to output with the setData function.
I appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know PHP, but from what I just read, you have an "associative array." And [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) says an associative array is converted by `json_encode()` to an object. So you should use:

```
$("#price" + lastchar).html(data.price);
$("#matricule" + lastchar).html(data.matricule);
$("#tag" + lastchar).html(data.tag);
$("#ins_yr1" + lastchar).html(data.ins_yr1);
$("#Totalacq" + lastchar).html(data.Totalacq);
```

Comment: Thanks for your post. I just tried it but still no output. It seems that everything else is working ( posting to php,php file ), so I am still at a loss.

Comment: UPDATE: IT'S WORKING NOW. I believe the issue was that I left some headings on the php file comp_data.php that were somehow getting things messed up when the data was being passed back. So, thanks again John S for your help!